# Create a matrix with given data

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Suppose that a surveyor has made the following measurements related to the elevations of four nearby points.
>
> Point 1 is 360 feet above sea level.
>
> Point 2 is 422 feet above sea level.
>
> Point 3 is 501 feet above sea level.
>
> Point 3 is 143 feet above Point 1.
>
> Point 3 is 107 feet above Point 4.
>
> Point 4 is 32 feet above Point 1.
>
> Point 2 is 32 feet above Point 4.

Base on my understanding, I got
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}360 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 422 & 0 & 0 \\ 143 & 0 & 501 & 0\\32 & 32 & 107 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Because the last column is a zero column, I can not solve it by doing $Ax=b$. I must have a $b$ from the data above. Can someone give me a hint to construct $A$ and $b$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations you are given are (assuming that the zero-point is sea level):

$h_1 = 360 \\
h_2 = 422 \\
h_3 = 501 \\
h_3 = h_1 + 143 \rightarrow -h_1 + h_3 = 143 \\
h_3 = h_4 + 107 \rightarrow h_3 - h_4 = 107 \\
h_4 = h_1 + 32 \rightarrow h_1 - h_4 = 32 \\
h_2 = h_4 + 32 \rightarrow -h_2 + h_4 = 32$

So you have 7 equations in 4 unknowns, better hope they're consistent! You can construct the matrix form from these equations though.